# How to logged out from device B when resets password from device A

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt

In my app I'm using [devise-jwt](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt) tokens for user authentication. I've got case when user tries to reset password from device A but he is also logged in to the same account on device B. Is it possible to logged out user from device B in such case?

Comment: Which strategy you use? White list, Black list,...

Comment: @ThuyNguyen I've got `jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtBlacklist` in user's model

Comment: Can u provide an example of token?

Comment: @ThuyNguyen I think this is what we're looking for: `SELECT "jwt_blacklist".* FROM "jwt_blacklist" WHERE "jwt_blacklist"."jti" = $1 AND "jwt_blacklist"."exp" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["jti", "5d8042ad-8294-4725-a789-24f4e0a027a2"]`

Comment: Hm, Did you try with that? jwt_blacklist table is used to store revoked token, so I don't think query in jwt_blacklist table can solve your problem

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Sample of token as you requested: `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIzIiwic2NwIjoiYWNjb3VudCIsImF1ZCI6bnVsbCwiaWF0IjoxNTg4NzUxNzA0LCJleHAiOiIxNTkxMzgxNDUwIiwianRpIjoiY2M1MjNmYjYtYmM0Mi00MTg2LTk5Y2ItMTY2YTY2NTUzM2ZhIn0.G3_nPAT9jlg9c80oWTOmonXs0s3OHB6oiKpxoxGuvw8`

Answer (score 0):

You can use devise security extension [here is link for detail page](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security)

there are 7 additial devise modules in that gem but the one you need is 
:session_limitable which ensures, that there is only one session usable per account at once

short version installation steps:

```
gem 'devise-security'
# then run bundle install 
rails generate devise_security:install
# this to run generator
```

The generator adds optional configurations to 
config/initializers/devise-security.rb. 
Enable the modules you wish to use in the initializer 
you are ready to add Devise Security modules on top of 
Devise modules to any of your Devise models:

inside your model User or Account  you can add

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,.... , :session_limitable
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think u need to store time when user change password

Then try use this service

```
#check_token_service.rb

class CheckTokenService
  TOKEN_REGEX = /(?<token_type>\w+)\s(?<token>\S+)/.freeze

  def initialize(token, current_user)
    @current_user = current_user
    @token_decoder = Warden::JWTAuth::TokenDecoder.new.call(token.match(TOKEN_REGEX)['token'])
  end

  def perform
    Time.at(@token_decoder['exp'].to_i) > @current_user.change_password_at + Devise::JWT.config[:expiration_time]
  end
end
```

then call the service before all action

```
raise JWT::ExpiredSignature unless CheckTokenService.new(request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"], current_user).perform
```